# Error on the constructor OTPublisher

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, opentok

I'm creating a project similar to this one: https://github.com/TechnologyOne/OpenTok.Xamarin

I can run the application but it crashes when he tries to create a new OTPublisher constructor. Error from the application output: https://gist.github.com/joaowd/41d5fb2fe8894318909d24e0d748f2d0

In the GitHub file he passes to the constructor a delegate and a string but I get a error saying that he's expecting a OTPublisherSettings instead of a string:

```
_publisher = new OTPublisher(new PublisherDelegate(this), UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Name);
```

I tried different approaches like:

1.

```
var settings = new OTPublisherSettings();
settings.Name = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Name;
_publisher = new OTPublisher(new PublisherDelegate(this), settings);
```

2.

```
var settings = new OTPublisherSettings();

            settings.AudioTrack = true;
            settings.VideoTrack = true;
            settings.Name = "Test";

_publisher = new OTPublisher(new PublisherDelegate(this), settings);
```

3.

```
var CameraResolution = OTCameraCaptureResolution.High;
var CameraFrameRate = OTCameraCaptureFrameRate.OTCameraCaptureFrameRate30FPS;
_publisher = new OTPublisher(new PublisherDelegate(this), 
    "Test", CameraResolution, CameraFrameRate);
```

(the constructor also accepts 4 arguments).

Any idea whats happening?

Thank you, any question please ask.

File of the particular class: https://github.com/TechnologyOne/OpenTok.Xamarin/blob/master/OpenTok.Xamarin/VideoChatView.cs

Comment: If it crashes, please provide a stack trace.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is what I get from the application output: https://gist.github.com/joaowd/41d5fb2fe8894318909d24e0d748f2d0